# Can't get docker to forward ports

Tags: port-forwarding, docker

I've been following a [tutorial](http://prakhar.me/docker-curriculum/) to try and learn docker, however, for some reason I can't seem to access any of the ports it's meant to be opening. For some reason it just times out. Where can I look to get more details on why I'm not able to access this, or otherwise what can I do access the docker container.

Steps done so far:

```
$ docker run hello-world # works fine
$ docker run -d -P --name static-site prakhar1989/static-site # works and returns a docker container id
$ docker port static-site
443/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32768
80/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32769
```

Then I access one of the host through `http://localhost:32768/` but nothing. After reinstalling it doesn't even time out anymore and just says the site can't be reached.

Also, I tried accessing the container directly on those ports but without any success.

Answer (score 0):

For HTTP use port redirecting to port 80, i.e. access the site with `http://localhost:32769`.

HTTPS doesn't seem to be configured in this container.

Comment: Sorry, I did try both, neither work. The connection is just refused

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with a **reboot**  :/

I was having the same problem on a fresh Docker 1.12 install on Ubuntu 15.10.  After going through https://prakhar.me/docker-curriculum/, and I wasn't able to connect to the sample containers.  The http connection would just hang.